# PHP post method inside for loop causes infinite loop

Tags: php, for-loop

i have a set of fields say field1, field2,... field10.

i pass this value from one page to another and get the value using post method inside a for loop as follows..

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$txtfield.$i = $_POST[field.$i]; 

echo $txtfield.$i;
}
```

This makes an infinite loop printing the value of field1 continuously..

Finally this error occurs..

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\...
```

what is the mistake in this code???

Comment: On a side note put `field` in quotes.

Comment: Your problem doesn't lie in this loop. It only goes to 10.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the value "field", shouldn't it be a variable with a $?

Anyway, I think you wanted to do this:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
    $varname = ($txtfield . $i);
    $$varname = $_POST[field.$i]; 

    echo $$varname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning `$i` here each time to `$_POST[field.$i]`

```
$txtfield.$i = $_POST[field.$i]
```

Kind of like this, with the second line being a non-expression:

```
$i = $_POST[field.$i];
$txtfield.$i;
```